# Calculate the sum of time column in PostgreSql

Tags: postgresql, sum

Can anyone suggest me, the easiest way to find summation of time field in `POSTGRESQL`. i just find a solution for `MYSQL` but i need the `POSTGRESQL` version.

**MYSQL**: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054943/calculate-sum-time-with-mysql

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(timespent))) FROM myTable;
```

Demo Data

```
id   time 
1   1:23:23
2   4:00:23
3   9:23:23
```

**Desired Output**

14:47:09

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried this solution on sql fieddle:
[**link**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/637a7/3/0)

Table creation:

```
CREATE TABLE time_table (
 id integer, time time
);
```

Insert data:

```
INSERT INTO time_table (id,time) VALUES
  (1,'1:23:23'),
  (2,'4:00:23'),
  (3,'9:23:23')
```

query the data:

```
SELECT
  sum(s.time)
FROM 
  time_table s;
```

Answer (score 5):

What you want, is not possible. But you probably misunderstood the [`time` type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html): it represents a precise time-point in a day. It doesn't make much sense, to add two (or more) times. f.ex. `'14:00' + '14:00' = '28:00'` (but there are no 28th hour in a day).

What you probably want, is [`interval`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html) (which represents time intervals; hours, minutes, or even years). `sum()` supports `interval` arguments.

If you use intervals, it's just that simple:

```
SELECT sum(interval_col) FROM my_table;
```

Although, if you stick to the `time` type (but you have no reason to do that), you can cast it to `interval` to calculate with it:

```
SELECT sum(time_col::interval) FROM my_table;
```

But again, the result will be `interval`, because `time` values cannot exceed the 24th hour in a day.

*Note*: PostgreSQL will even do the cast for you, so `sum(time_col)` should work too, but the result is `interval` in this case too.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to calculate sum of some field, according another field, you can do this:

```
select
    keyfield,
    sum(time_col::interval) totaltime
    FROM myTable
    GROUP by keyfield
```

Output example:
keyfield; totaltime
"Gabriel"; "10:00:00"
"John";    "36:00:00"
"Joseph";  "180:00:00"

Data type of totaltime is interval.