# Sum HH:mm in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, time, sum

I need to sum `HH:mm` in PostgreSQL, like this:

```
'01:52' + '02:08' = '04:00'
```

It's for a service desk software (calculate service time).

It's possible? Thank you guys!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate the sum of time column in PostgreSql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30487420/calculate-the-sum-of-time-column-in-postgresql)

Comment: Sorry, i searched for an aswner before, but do not find it. :|

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use interval?..

```
t=# select '01:52'::interval + '02:08'::interval;
 ?column?
----------
 04:00:00
(1 row)
```

Comment: I did not expect it to be that easy hehe. I had seen the functions, but I did not realize that it would work like this in the syntax. Thanks, solved the problem. :>

Comment: Postgresql is really good at date/time math. Esp if you have to consider timezones while doing it.